# Error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to change the Datatype of my primarykey to String in sequelize and am getting the following error while trying to create using upsert.

```
error:  SequelizeDatabaseError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

here is the code:

```
 id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: true,
      autoIncrement: false,
      field: "id"
    }
```

How do I make this work? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS):

> Technically, a primary key constraint is simply a combination of a unique constraint and a not-null constraint.

You cannot create nullable primary key.

```
  ...
    allowNull: false,
  ...
```

Comment: Are you saying I can't change the datatype of primary key?

Comment: You can change the type of primary key, but it is always **not null**.

Comment: how do I change it to a string type?

Comment: Try with `allowNull: false`.

Comment: You can change the type with this SQL: `alter table *table_name* alter id type text`. Unfortunately, I don't use sequelize.